# Discrete surface integral with cumsum

Tags: matlab, probability, cdf, cumsum

I have a matrix z(x,y) [image: Arbitrary multinomial pdf := z]
This is an NxN abitary pdf constructed from a unique Kernel density estimation (i.e. not a usual pdf and it doesn't have a function). It is multivariate and can't be separated and is discrete data.

I wan't to construct a NxN matrix (F(x,y)) that is the cumulative distribution function in 2 dimensions of this pdf so that I can then randomly sample the F(x,y) = P(x < X ,y < Y);

Analytically I think the CDF of a multivariate function is the surface integral of the pdf.

What I have tried is using the `cumsum` function in order to calculate the surface integral and tested this with a multivariate normal against the analytical solution and there seems to be some discrepancy between the two:

```
% multivariate parameters
delta = 100;
mu = [1 1];
Sigma = [0.25 .3; .3 1];
x1 = linspace(-2,4,delta); x2 = linspace(-2,4,delta);
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
% Calculate Normal multivariate pdf
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
% My attempt at a numerical surface integral 
FN = cumsum(cumsum(F,1),2);
% Normalise the CDF
FN = FN./max(max(FN));
X = [X1(:) X2(:)];
% Analytic solution to a multivariate normal pdf
p = mvncdf(X,mu,Sigma);
p = reshape(p,delta,delta);
% Highlight the difference
dif = p - FN;
error = max(max(sqrt(dif.^2)));
% %% Plot
figure(1)
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); zlabel('Probability Density');
figure(2)
surf(X1,X2,FN);
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2');
figure(3);
surf(X1,X2,p);
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2');
figure(5)
surf(X1,X2,dif)
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2');
```

Particularly the error seems to be in the transition region which is the most important.

Does anyone have any better solution to this problem or see what I'm doing wrong??
Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** This is the desired outcome of the cumulative integration, The reason this function is of value to me is that when you randomly generate samples from this function on the closed interval [0,1] the higher weighted (i.e. the more likely) values appear more often in this way the samples converge on the expected value(s) (in the case of multiple peaks) this is desired outcome for algorithms such as particle filters, neural networks etc.
[image: multivariate cdf]

Comment: Using `trapz` rather than `cumsum` might be more accurate: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html

Comment: @David how would I go about producing the CDF function with 'trapz' as far as I know 'trapz' evaluates the discrete integral into numerical area (or volume of the 2D case)?

Comment: Oh of course, sorry, I don't that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the 1-dimensional case first. You have a function represented by a vector `F` and want to numerically integrate. `cumsum(F)` will do that, but it uses a poor form of numerical integration. Namely, it treats `F` as a step function. You could instead do a more accurate numerical integration using the [Trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule).

The 2-dimensional case is no different. Your use of `cumsum(cumsum(F,1),2)` is again treating `F` as a step function, and the numerical errors resulting from that assumption only get worse as the number of dimensions of integration increases. There exist 2-dimensional analogues of the Trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule. Since there's a bit too much math to repeat here, take a look here:
http://onestopgate.com/gate-study-material/mathematics/numerical-analysis/numerical-integration/2d-trapezoidal.asp.

Comment: I had a look at the link and it seems to good description of how to numerically integrate in the 2 dimensional case, I'm still unsure how to use this method produce the function (Discrete surface function := Matrix NxN F(x,y)), that acurately represents the surface integral, that I can then randomly sample?

Comment: @Chriso For initial purposes, your `cumsum(cumsum(F,1),2)` approach should work, albeit with suboptimal accuracy. You should update your question with the picture you get from doing that (so that there are pictures of both PDF And CDF), then elaborate on what you mean by "randomly sample." If what you're trying to do is randomly sample a multivariate Gaussian distribution, this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: No problem I'll update the question with more information. FYI I am testing this with multivariate guassian because it has an exact solution and I can check the accuracy of the algorithm but the method will be used for an arbitrary pdf constructed from the convolution of multiple weighted kernels resulting in one essentially arbitary shaped pdf. This pdf I see no other way to sample randomly other than to construct a cdf and sample  F(x,y) = P(x < X ,y < Y) as I stated in my question. If you do know of another way to numerically sample this function please let me know, regards Chris

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention the reason I sample the CDF is because the more likely values come out more often which is the objective. (This is part of a Particle Filter algorithm)

Comment: @Chriso If all you're doing is sampling your current method may already be accurate enough. Note you can probably sample with a two step method: (1) sample discrete distribution of kernel weights to determine kernel (2) sample kernel distribution (multivariate Gaussian). I'm skeptical that you actually need to be doing numerical integration.

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT need to compute the 2-dimensional integral of the probability density function in order to sample from the distribution. If you are computing the 2-d integral, you are going about the problem incorrectly.

Here are two ways to approach the sampling problem.

(1) You write that you have a kernel density estimate. A kernel density estimate is a special case of a mixture density. Any mixture density can be sampled by first selecting one kernel (perhaps differently or equally weighted, same procedure applies), and then sampling from that kernel. (That applies in any number of dimensions.) Typically the kernels are some relatively simple distribution such as a Gaussian distribution so that it is easy to sample from it.

(2) Any joint density P(X, Y) is equal to P(X | Y) P(Y) (and equivalently P(Y | X) P(X)). Therefore you can sample from P(Y) (or P(X)) and then from P(X | Y). In order to sample from P(X | Y), you will need to integrate P(X, Y) along a line Y = y (where y is the sampled value of Y), but (this is crucial) you only need to integrate along that line; you don't need to integrate over all values of X and Y.

If you tell us more about your problem, I can help with the details.